# .htaccess url rewriting omitting last character of the parameter

Tags: php, regex, .htaccess, url-rewriting

I am developing a web app in which name of other website are supposed to be given as parameters, am rewriting urls using .htaccess file on my apache web server, this is the code i wrote in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\_\-]+(\.)[a-z0-9\_\.\-]+)[^(site.php)] site.php?url=$1
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\_\-]+(\.)[a-z0-9\_\.\-]+)[^(site.php)]/ site.php?url=$1
```

I wrote `[^(site.php)]` this because it was passing site.php as parameter as site.php was a match for my regex. This is working the right way but the only problem is that the last character of the parameter is omitted, for example, when am writting:

```
www.mywebsite.com/google.com
```

its taking `google.co` and omitting the last `m`. If am passing `google.co.in`, its taking `google.co.i` and omitting the `n`. What can be the reason for this?

Comment: All characters lose any special meaning inside a character set, so `[^(site.php)]` means 'not any characters (,s,i,t,...'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you use `[^(site.php)]` (and it doesn't means what you think), it will match the last character of your url. You should use a RewriteCond, you can try :

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9\_\-]+(\.)[a-z0-9\_\.\-]+)/?$ site.php?url=$1
```

Wich means : do not rewrite for existing file or directory